# How can I be more effective in ADOM?

Tags: adom

The more I play ADOM, the more I realise there is a pattern in the way I die. It's always in the first dungeon, where I have to find the carpenter, and I will seem to do fine until some monster, different every time, but of no rare type, will come along and start beating me and I for some reason will be unable to even hit it. There is nothing special about these monsters, once a fire beetle killed me, after I had killed 3 beetles before it in the same playthrough, another time a skeleton.... The game just seems to pick a monster and say "right, you are now invincible, go kill the player" and of course, I can do nothing about it, because almost none of the classes I play (all apart from Necromancer, Elementalist, Priest and spellcaster classes in general) can do anything in the first 6 or so levels apart from basic attacks.

Just now I was playing a monk, I reached a level where, apparently, I could use "circular kick" but even that I couldn't find out how to do. Not that it would've helped, as I had no way of healing myself in combat.

Am I missing something? is there some way to ensure I get through at least the first dungeon without dying stupid deaths every single time?

Comment: The circular kick (as well as other class abilities) can be used from the Ctrl-X menu. However, I wouldn't recommend it unless you have no other alternative; kicking is weaker than using a decent weapon, and the 2500 energy cost leaves you completely defenseless for a turn and a half after your attack.

Answer (score 2):

I have sucked at ADOM too. This is what I do to do better.

1. go to www.adom.de and read the forums. Ask questions there. Its a special Adom forum
2. read the [Adom wiki](http://ancardia.wikia.com/wiki/ADOM_Wiki) (lists newbie friendly classes)
3. read the [improved Adom guidebook](http://adomgb.sweb.cz/)

Drakeling Paladins have good early game survival. You will run into a lot of trouble in 1 dungeon mid-game, but worry about getting there first.

Talents: Miser,Alert. These don't do much, but it lets you get 'treasure hunter' with your next talent. This radically improves your drops. After this get the 'speed talents' next. Anything that increases speed.

Starsign: Pick Candle. Google 'adom starsign selector' this lets you pick a starsign. you can ask for a link on the adom forums. This is generally not considered scumming. Candle is generally considered the best starsign. Especially for beginners.

Get familiar with f1, f7. This sets your tactics. walk around in defensive mode with f7. When you go to attack switch to f1 (bezerk) switch back immediately.

Drakelings Power: press m and a direction to spit. Very good missile weapon. Best part is that its attack power and accuracy does NOT drop when you are in defensive mode. So you can go f7 and use it when you get in trouble. Note this makes you hungry. So watch your food. I always buy food at the first town before going anywhere.

Go to the infinite dungeon to start. Stay on the first 3 levels. Go up and down. This should be easy to get you levels and will give you a good shot at getting potion,scrolls, rings, amulets, etc...

read the scrolls you have to learn them. Take off items in case you get something that destroys weapons. use identify scrolls to identify potions first. If you find holy water potions dip your identify scroll in it. Reading a blessed identify scroll will ID everything in your inventory.

Stair hope some between level 3 & 4. in the ID, you have to go down 3 levels to increase Danger Level (its one level in most other dungeons). Higher dungeon level means higher drops. So at 4, you get a little better drops. The advantage of staying at low DL drops is that most potions, scrolls, etc... are DL 1 so you increase your odds of getting them because there are not higher DL items. Get 7-8 levels here.

Go back and continue with the newbie dungeon. This is a good way to learn some mechanics.

One note. Watch hunger. Its nasty how you can just starve and not see it.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips to make things easier:

- Play a class born with Healing skill and/or try to play under the
  Candle birthsign
- Always heal to full after each battle (use 'w5'
  command generously)
- If you play a melee class, you are not really supposed to have any special abilities (with a few exceptions). Basic attacks will be your bread and butter for the entire game.

Race/class combos are not balanced by design and some are much easier than others. For starters I'd suggest Orc Barbarian (they start with high strength and heavy armor) or Gray Elf Priest (medium starting armor + excellent spellcasting ability)